# How to check whether the post belongs to a subcategory of taxonomy category in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, archive, taxonomy

My goal is to display conditional content in an archive page in Wordpress based on whether post belongs to the main category of custom taxonomy and any subcategories of the certain taxonomy category.
I know how to achieve this for the plain post categories and child subcategories.

```
if (is_category('dogs') || cat_is_ancestor_of('dogs', get_query_var( 'cat' )) { echo 'Successs';
```

The first part works fine

```
is_tax('advert_category', 380) ) ||
```

but how do I check whether the post belongs to a subcategory of taxonomy category 380?

Answer (score 0):

I believe [`is_tax()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_tax) is the wrong function to use to check whether a post has a certain term or not. [`is_tax()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_tax) simply checks if you are on a taxonomy archive or not.

You should be using [`has_term()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term), which does just that - it checks if a post has a certain term.

When we start looking at terms, the [`get_term_children`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_children) function becomes available to us:

```
<?php
$term_id = 380;
$taxonomy_name = 'advert_category';
$term_children = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy_name );

echo '<ul>';
foreach ( $term_children as $child ) {
    $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy_name );
    echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $child, $taxonomy_name ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
?>
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: How could I use it if I'd like to show posts that have child terms that belong to only specific parent term in an archive page? It is this sort of conditional content I'm looking for.

Comment: To clarify, you want to build an archive page which show posts from the parent category and any post in a category that is a child of the parent category?

Comment: Exactly, except that it's a custom taxonomy 'advert_category'.